# Angularjs 1.5 Nested Components bindings

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-1.5, angular-components

am trying to *pass a value* from a **parent-component** to his nested **child-component** in angular 1.5

The value can be updated from the parents, but child cannot edit it, just show it. So is a **one-way binding  '<'**  right ?

And i cannot pass the child component right in the parent component declaration, because the parent component would have other uses too.

> The point is my parent-component have common data stored, but them
>   children gonna use it in different ways.
>
> And the parent-component gonna be used multiples times, with different
>   children, thats why i cannot pass the children inside parent
>   declaration. I need to bind the info, for auto updates purposes, when
>   parents updates the data, must be reflected by the children

HTML

```
<parent-component ng-transclude>
  <child-component name="$ctrl.characters.arya"></child-component>
  <child-component name="$ctrl.characters.john"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

JS

```
   // Parent Component declaration
// /////////////////////////
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .component("parentComponent", {
      transclude: true,
      controller: "ParentComponentController",
      template: 
        '<div class="parent-c"></div>'
    });
 })();



// Parent Component Controller
// /////////////////////////
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ParentComponentController', ParentComponentController);

  function ParentComponentController() {
    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.characters = {};
    $ctrl.characters.arya = "Arya Stark";
    $ctrl.characters.john = "John Snow";
  }
})();




//CHILD Component declaration
// /////////////////////////
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .component("childComponent", {
      bindings: {
        name: '<'
      },
      controller: "ChildComponentController",
      template: 
        '<div class="child-c"' +
          '<h3>Im a child Component</h3>' +
          '<p><strong>Name: </strong>{{$ctrl.name}}</p>' +
        '</div>'
    });
 })();



// CHILD Component Controller
// /////////////////////////
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ChildComponentController', ChildComponentController);

  function ChildComponentController() {
    var $ctrl = this;
  }
})();
```

---

[Check the WORKING SAMPLE on plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hqMsfAxAZmDk9f0sOAGs)

---

The **require** attribute is for components communication, but i'm trying to use it with no success :(, need a piece of light here.

Comment: Do you want to pass a name as an attribute to the component (through bindings) or by inheritance from the parent (through require)?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use : `<child-component name="$parent.$ctrl.characters.arya"></child-component>`to pass a value from a parent-component to his nested child-component

Comment: Hi ! thanks for your answer.
This works, but seems too easy to be real, is there some bad performance or bad practice about using this ?

Comment: It's better to have  self contained element . You could easily use them in another project. But generally if you need external informations,inject them or bind them.

Comment: The point is my parent-component have common data stored, but them children gonna use them of different ways.

And the parent-component gonna be used multiples times, with different children, thats why i cannot pass the children inside parent declaration.

I need to bind the info, for auto updates purposes, when parents updates the data, must be reflected by the children.

Answer (score 1):

There are different issues with your code:

```
  function ParentComponentController() {
    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.characters = {};
    $ctrl.characters.arya = "Arya Stark";
    $ctrl.characters.john = "John Snow";
  }
```

You don't need to define a local variable for this since not changing context anywhere.

```
controller: "ParentComponentController",
```

Don't pass a string to this property, pass a reference:

```
controller: ParentComponentController,
```

Then if you want to pass `name` through the parent controller with require in the child component:

```
require: { parent: '^^parentComponent' },
```

Now that you have the parent controller bound to child you can use it with:

```
{{$ctrl.parent.characters.arya}}
```

in the template.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3PRgQSGdBEIDKuUSyDLY?p=preview

If you need to pass the name as an attribute to your child components, you have to put the child components inside the parent's template so you can call $ctrl.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1H7OlwbumkNuKKrbu4Vr?p=preview

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply.
On plunkr i have everything in one file, but in local i have 3 files for each component: 1 component.js, 1 component.controller.js, 1 component.template.html  thats why i defined local variable and use string instead of reference. 

There is a way to get the Name as an attribute, but outside of the parent template ? like store the name in a child component variable or something like that.